# xml validate value null

Tags: java, xml, junit4

i will be getting an xml from a web app, something like the one given below.

```
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>J</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Some Message</body>
</note>
```

will i be able to assert if the value at  tag is null something similar to this

```
<note>
<to></to>
<from>J</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Some Message</body>
</note>
```

i need to do it using java and junit.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: How are you parsing this xml ? Are you creating an object ?

Comment: @TimofeyStolbov i like it :) +1

Comment: nice one man.. but i need directions on how to go about, and this s sort of my first time with XML.

Comment: I will not be able to create an object for the xml. so any other way i can go about?

Answer (score 2):

Since this is an open ended question I will try to give you one easy solution to it.

Use [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) to parse xml to object and object to xml.

You can get started with XStream in 10 min read [this](http://xstream.codehaus.org/tutorial.html).

Once you have created your object say `Note` then you can say in your junit

```
assertNotNull(note.getTo());
```

Sample Code below:

My Note Class

```
public class Note {
private String to = null;
private String from = null;
private String heading = null;
private String body = null;

public Note(String to, String from, String heading, String body) {
    super();
    this.to = to;
    this.from = from;
    this.heading = heading;
    this.body = body;
}

public String getTo() {
    return to;
}

public void setTo(String to) {
    this.to = to;
}

public String getFrom() {
    return from;
}

public void setFrom(String from) {
    this.from = from;
}

public String getHeading() {
    return heading;
}

public void setHeading(String heading) {
    this.heading = heading;
}

public String getBody() {
    return body;
}

public void setBody(String body) {
    this.body = body;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return new StringBuilder().append("To = ").append(this.getTo())
            .append(" ,From = ").append(this.getFrom())
            .append(" ,Heading = ").append(this.getHeading())
            .append(" ,Body = ").append(this.getBody()).toString();
}
```

}

Class which will convert XML to Object and Object to XML

```
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.DomDriver;

public class TestXStream {

public String getXMLFromObject(Note object) {
    XStream xStream = new XStream(new DomDriver());
    return xStream.toXML(object);
}

public Note getNoteFromXML(String noteXML) {
    XStream xStream = new XStream(new DomDriver());
    return (Note) xStream.fromXML(noteXML);
}
```

}

And Sample JUnit Test Case:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;


public class XStreamJunitTest {

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
}

@Test
public void test() {
    Note note = new Note("TestTo", "TestFrom", "TestHeading", "TestBody");
    TestXStream testXStream = new TestXStream();
    note = testXStream.getNoteFromXML(testXStream.getXMLFromObject(note));
    assertNotNull(note.getBody());
}
```

}

Hope this helps and gets you going.